# Dojo/Dijit: set entries id attribute in select

Tags: javascript, select, dojo, dijit.form

I'm trying to build a < select > with dijit\dojo having a JsonRest store (obtained by calling a remote Rest service).

the code is:

```
var storeEntity = new JsonRest({
    target: contextPath + "/api/myEntity/?param=123",
    identifier : "idEntity"
});

var selectEntity = new Select({
    id: "selectEntity",
    name: "selectEntity",
    style: "width:250px",
    store: storeEntity,
    labelAttr : "someProperty"
}, "selectEntityContainer");
```

with this I can set the label (and it works), but i can't set the id of the values, and i can't also select the values.
I know that if my Json has the property "id" it goes automatically as the id of the entries, but if i want to change the attribute taken as id, how i can do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest), there is a property called `idProperty` in your `JsonRest` store. So it should be:

```
var storeEntity = new JsonRest({
    target: contextPath + "/api/myEntity/?param=123",
    idProperty : "idEntity"
});
```